# AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'button'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

When I tried to run this code I had got the Error:

`AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'button'`

in the function `fillLabel` how can I get the **position x,y from the QLabel image when I click the left mouse button**(as long as **right mouse button isn't clicked** to terminate the positions selection)? I can use QCrusor, but the position value will come from the whole MainWindow, I just want the positions coming from QLabel image.

The image used here is this:

[image: original]

```
import sys
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.io import imread, imsave

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication, Qt, QDir
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1009, 577)        
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        #------- Initialization --------------------------
        self.directory = None
        self.label     = None
        self.image     = None
        #------- Seed PB ---------------------------------------       
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Rockwell")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)

        self.PB_Seeds_Button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.PB_Seeds_Button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 440, 151, 41))        
        self.PB_Seeds_Button.setFont(font)
        self.PB_Seeds_Button.setObjectName("PB_Seeds_Button")
        #------- LB_Image_Frame ---------------------------------------
        self.frame_4 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 361, 361))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Rockwell")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.frame_4.setFont(font)
        self.frame_4.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_4.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_4.setObjectName("frame_4")
        self.frame_4.setAcceptDrops(True)

        self.LB_Image_Orig = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame_4)
        self.LB_Image_Orig.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 361, 361))
        self.LB_Image_Orig.setObjectName("LB_Image_Orig")

        #------- LB_Seg_Frame ---------------------------------------
        self.frame_5 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 20, 361, 361))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Rockwell")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.frame_5.setFont(font)
        self.frame_5.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_5.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_5.setObjectName("frame_5")

        self.LB_Image_Seg = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame_5)
        self.LB_Image_Seg.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 361, 361))
        self.LB_Image_Seg.setObjectName("LB_Image_Seg")

        #------- LB_Combo_Box ---------------------------------------
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 440, 69, 22))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Rockwell")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.comboBox.setFont(font)
        self.comboBox.setMaxVisibleItems(7)
        self.comboBox.setMaxCount(7)
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.comboBox.setCurrentIndex(0)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        self.PB_Seeds_Button.clicked.connect(self.fillLabel)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Dicom"))

        self.PB_Seeds_Button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Label Areas"))

        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(4, _translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(5, _translate("MainWindow", "5"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(6, _translate("MainWindow", "6"))

        Image = imread('image.png')    
        self.label = np.zeros_like(Image)

        self.image = QPixmap('image.png').copy()
        self.LB_Image_Orig.setPixmap(self.image)
        self.LB_Image_Orig.adjustSize()
        QApplication.processEvents()
        if os.path.exists("image.png"):
           os.remove("image.png") 
    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    def fillLabel(self,event):
        while( event.button() != QtCore.Qt.RightButton)):
            if(event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton):
                x = event.pos().x()
                y = event.pos().y()

                if(self.label is not None):
                    x = round(self.posx*(self.label.shape[0] / self.LB_Image_Orig.geometry().height()))
                    y = round(self.posy*(self.label.shape[1] / self.LB_Image_Orig.geometry().width()))
                    self.label[x,y] = self.comboBox.currentIndex()
                    if(np.sum(self.label)):
                        self.mask = QPixmap(self.label)
                        self.LB_Image_Seg.setPixmap(self.mask)
                        #self.LB_Image_Seg.resize(pixmap2.width(),pixmap2.height())
                        self.LB_Image_Seg.adjustSize()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    screenShape = QtWidgets.QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry()
    MainWindow.resize(screenShape.width(), screenShape.height())
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The solution was like this:
  first I added x, and y variables to the class, and connected the event ov clicking on the label to the function choseLabel:

```
        self.x         = None
        self.y         = None 
        self.LB_Image_Orig.mousePressEvent = self.choseLabel
```

- Then changed the function `fillLabel`to be:

```
    def fillLabel(self,event):
        if(self.label is not None):        
                if(self.x is not None):
                    y = round(self.y*(self.label.shape[1] / self.LB_Image_Orig.geometry().height()))
                    x = round(self.x*(self.label.shape[0] / self.LB_Image_Orig.geometry().width()))
                    print(x,y)
                    self.label[x,y] = self.comboBox.currentIndex()
```

- The position selection function:

```
    def choseLabel(self,event):
        if(self.image is not None):
            self.x = event.pos().x()
            self.y = event.pos().y()
            self.fillLabel(event)
```